# TFS Client Side API equivalent constructs in VSTS Client Side API for GIT

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops

I currently have a project that uses TFS Client Side API. The project is in C#. The project has references to the following constructs:

- VersionControlServer
- VersionControlLabel
- Item
- ItemSet
- VersionSpec

Here is sample of current code:

```
using (TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(collectionUri)))
{
    VersionControlServer vcServer = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    ItemSet itemSet = vcServer.GetItems("$/", RecursionType.OneLevel);
    foreach (Item item in itemSet.Items)
    {
        //do stuff with the item
    }
}
```

Now I have projects in VSTS (configure to use Git) that i would like to target. From what i have seen so far the above constructs do not exist in VSTS Client Side API if you're using Git source.

What are the equivalent constructs in VSTS Client side API where the source is Git?

Here is my VSTS sample code:

```
  VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsOrTfsCollectionUrl), new VssClientCredentials());

//The ProjectHttpClient
 ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();

 BuildHttpClient buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();

//Get Basic Project - Shallow Reference
 IEnumerable<TeamProjectReference> projects = 
 projectClient.GetProjects().Result;

//Create GIT since some projects use Git
GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

..projectName.. and other code here..

TeamProject theProject = projectClient.GetProject(projectName).Result;

List<GitRepository> gitRepositoryList = 
gitClient.GetRepositoriesAsync(theProject.Name).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code you mentioned is for Team Foundation Version Control System(TFVC), not for Git. TFVC and Git are different version control system, the constructs of the API is different too. So you won't find the same constructs for Git. If you want to get the items in a Git repository, use `GetItemsAsync()` method in GitHttpClient.

By the way, the TFS Client Side API you mentioned is the legacy SOAP API and the VSTS Client Side API is the new Rest API. They are both available for TFS&VSTS.